# Getting error of undefined variable in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3, insert-update

I am writing code for displaying data from mysql db to front end. I am using code igniter for this. I am newbie in CI and in oops too. that's why i am not able to find correct way to solve my error.

This is my controller:

```
<?php
    class Menu_items extends CI_Controller {

     function _Menu_items(){  
      $this->load->model('Menu_items_model');
     }


     public function index(){
      $query = $this->Menu_items_model->get_items();
      $data['EMPLOYEES'] = null;
      if($query)
      {
        $data['EMPLOYEES'] =  $query;
      }
      $this->load->view('layouts/sidebar.php', $data);
     }
    }
?>
```

My Model:

```
<?php
class Menu_items_model extends CI_Model { 

 function get_items(){
  $this->db->select("MENU_ID,MENU_DISPLAY");
  $this->db->from('app_menu_items');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query ->result(); 
 }
}
?>
```

my view where i got this error:

```
<?php
    if (is_array($result['EMPLOYEES'])) 
      {
       foreach ($result as $row) 
      {?>
         <li><?php echo $row->MENU_ID;?></li>
         <li><?php echo $row->MENU_DISPLAY;?></li> 
      }
     <?php  } ?>
       else
        {
       echo 'record not found';
     <?php  } ?>
```

Comment: Only use blockquotes for actual quotes and use bold sparingly for emphasis, not to attract attention, so please remove it.

Comment: ON which line are you getting this error?

Comment: In view foreach loop `$result`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view is checking for the wrong variable.

Try:

```
if (isset($EMPLOYEES) && is_array($EMPLOYEES))
{
    foreach ($EMPLOYEES as $row)
```

Comment: @amitsutar See my update. Also, whenever you ask for help make sure to post the actual error text and line number of your issue or else it's annoying to help you. I would normally just close your question without hesitation...

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the variable $result['EMPLOYEES'].
instead use the variable $EMPLOYEES in your view

```
foreach ($EMPLOYEES as $row) 
  {?>
     <li><?php echo $row->MENU_ID;?></li>
     <li><?php echo $row->MENU_DISPLAY;?></li> 
  }
```

Comment: had you also edited  if (is_array($result['EMPLOYEES']))  to  if (is_array($EMPLOYEES]))?

Comment: ` if (isset($EMPLOYEES['EMPLOYEES']) && is_array($EMPLOYEES['EMPLOYEES'])){
            var_dump($EMPLOYEES);die;
              foreach($EMPLOYEES  as $row) 
           {?>
               <li><?php echo $row->MENU_ID;?></li>
               <li><?php echo $row->MENU_DISPLAY;?></li> 
          <?php  }} ?>` my this code hides my previous error but data is not still visible

Comment: I don't think $EMPLOYEES['EMPLOYEES'] has any value as per your code and for that reason if condition is not satisfied and foreach loop is executed.
See the stuff in var_dump($EMPLOYEES) out of if condition.